# Convert My sql query into active records query codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE (Circle LIKE '%D%' OR CLI LIKE '%D%' OR Operator LIKE '%D%') AND Dept = 'Sale'
```

I just want it like $this->db->like('Circle','%D%') with Dept with 'and'.

Comment: Take a look on https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the codeigniter doc, it's an easy one :

```
$this->db->where("(Circle LIKE '%D%' OR CLI LIKE '%D%' OR Operator LIKE '%D%')")
         ->where("dept", "Sale");
$query = $this->db->get("cdr");
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Is it possible to use or_like in this

Comment: $this->db->where('dept','Sale');
$this->db->or_like('Cli', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
$this->db->or_like('Circle', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
$this->db->or_like('Operator', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));

Comment: If you do that, you will lose the priority on the whole like clause. In your question you want (x+x)+x not x+x+x